# Eager load Imager transforms in Craft Commerce

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, eager-loading, plugin-imager

I am using [Imager](https://github.com/aelvan/Imager-Craft) to create my image transforms. I am on a category page and I want to list all of the products.

I did a quick `.with(['cf_shop_assets'])` optimization and wanted to continue with the image transforms.

Frankly, I don't know where to start?

```html
{% set products = craft.commerce.products.relatedTo(category).with(['cf_shop_assets']) %}
{% if products|length %}
    <div class="shop_container block listing_format">
        {% for product in products %}

        {% set variants = product.variants %}
        {% set variant = product.defaultVariant %}

        <div class="shop_item">
            <div class="more_info">
                <a href="{{ product.url }}">
                    {% set image = product.cf_shop_assets[0] ?? null %}
                    {% if image|length %}
                        {% set transformedImage = craft.imager.transformImage(image, {
                            width: 300,
                            quality: 90,
                            format: 'jpg',
                            bgColor: '#EFEFDE',
                            effects: { sharpen: true }
                        }) %}
                        <figure>
                            <img src="{{ transformedImage.url }}" class="image_full_width" width="{{ transformedImage.width }}" height="{{ transformedImage.height }}" alt="{{ image.title }} {{ gl_meta.cf_altText }}" />
                        </figure>
                    {% endif %}
                    <h2>{{ product.title }}</h2>
                </a>
            </div>

            […]

        {% endfor %}
    </div>
{% endif %}
```

The code works, but it only saves about 5 queries.

Would somebody be so kind to show me how to eager load Imager transforms?

I need Imager because I don't want to use transparent PNGs. There's no native way to transform a PNG to JPG and adding a background color.

Is this even possible?

Comment: Those plugin related questions are always difficult to answer because we have to dig deep into the plugin - unless the creator appears. I would suggest you to contact the creator directly and ask him. I doubt it's possible but maybe he could help you create this feature

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eager loading is used to reduce the number of database queries. Imager doesn't store any data in the database, it's completely file-based, so it's not relevant to use eager-loading in relation to it.

Comment: But since Craft can [eager-load image transforms](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/dev/eager-loading-elements.html#eager-loading-image-transform-indexes) using the `withTransforms` parameter, it would make sense that there should also be a way to have it eager-load Imager transforms, no?